# Converting GeoTIFF to PNG results in completely black image

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, dem, png

I have a set of DEM tiles (TIFF format) retrieved from https://cteco.uconn.edu/data/download/flight2016/index.htm which I would like to convert to 16-bit PNG format so that I can use them as heightmaps in Unreal Engine 5.

Referencing [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206537/geotiff-to-16-bit-tiff-png-or-bmp-image-for-heightmap) and [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332234/converting-grayscale-geotiff-to-png-using-qgis-results-in-all-black-image), I downloaded QGIS3 and used the `Raster → Conversion → Translate` menu to attempt conversion to `UInt16` with the following command:

```
gdal_translate -ot UInt16 -of PNG H:/Programming/Heightmaps/840630nw_x0_y0.tif H:/Programming/Heightmaps/output.png
```

The resulting image, however, is completely black and trying to import it into UE5 gives me a completely flat landscape so it's not just the preview unable to render. When I inspect its properties using the Windows context menu, I see that the pixel depth is 64 bits as opposed to the 16 I would expect. If I try any of the other output data types such as `Byte`, I get a depth of 8 bits which results in a blocky heightmap.

I don't work in the GIS space and have never done any image manipulation so talk of bands and depth goes a bit over my head. I am hoping someone can explain what might be going wrong and how I can fix it.

**EDIT:** Results from commands suggested by @user2856 [here](https://gist.github.com/heath3n/e8815fe199e997d6a0a9df753d015862).

Comment: Works for me.  Make sure you download the file labelled "DEM", not "TIFF", e.g. http://cteco.uconn.edu/download/DEM/2016/tiles/790755_nw.zip. The zip contains a GeoTIFF, but it's the actual elevation data, not just an image.  I then ran `gdal_translate -ot UInt16 -of PNG 790755_nw.tif 790755_nw.png` and got a single band 16bit PNG with correct elevation values (checked in QGIS).  If this is not working for you, edit your question and add the outputs of `gdalinfo -stats 840630nw_x0_y0.tif` and the same for the output png.

Comment: Forgot to mention... my output png looked completely black when I accidentally opened it in the default Windows image viewer, but that because that software was designed to handle pictures, i.e 3 or 4 channel (band) RGB or RGB+Alpha 8bit per channel files.  I notice Windows reports your output as 64bit, which makes me think you may have downloaded the "TIFF" image (your output png would have 4 channels, each 16bit == 64bit). If your input tif is a few mb file size (790755_nw.zip DEM is 3.7mb), you've got the elevation, if it's hundreds (790755_nw.zip TIFF is >300mb) you got the aerial imagery.

Comment: Okay; interesting. I re-downloaded all the tiles making sure to get the DEM versions. I thought maybe that solved my problem since the first one I converted came out properly as 16-bit. However the second is still producing a 64-bit result. I also get an error in QGIS with that one: `Warning 1: for band 1, nodata value has been clamped to 0, the original value being out of range.` I am updating the question with the results from the console commands.

Comment: No your output PNG is 16 bit according to the gdalinfo output, the only difference I can see is the NoData value metadata. Try adding `-a_nodata None` in "Additional command-line parameters" - `gdal_translate -ot UInt16 -of PNG -a_nodata None 840625_nw.tif 840625_nw.png`

Comment: Hmm it got rid of the error but Windows still shows that file as having 64-bit depth although I see from gdalinfo that it is indeed UInt16. I get the same flat plane when importing either result into UE5 though so it seems even the one that's "working" isn't actually working.

Comment: I think this might be a UE5 issue, which I know nothing about. The PNGs work fine in QGIS - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fwON.png

Comment: Maybe UE5 is rendering the landscape by using the full Uint16 range while your data values are between 222 and 294 which are very close to the black end of the range?

Comment: It's hard to know; the landscape documentation is only about a paragraph long which mentions that the input format must either be 16-bit PNG or RAW file. When I use an 8-bit PNG it does produce proper heights and looks generally like how I'd expect it to, but it's very blocky which I gathered from the linked questions is because it needs to be 16-bit. I'll ask around on the Unreal forums I suppose. Thank you for all your help though.

Comment: I am translating a mapbox png with height values for use in Unreal and I had to scale my image to get it to work correctly.  I used '-scale', min, max, '32768', '65535',  min=min elevation and max = max elevation.  I have a program that produces a png here https://github.com/delebash/unreal_mapbox_bridge. For live view check the Demo page.  Also I found this project that might help you https://github.com/iwer/GeotiffLandscape